# how can I create AA based wallet with Safe AuthKit?

Tags: safe-core-sdk

im trying to create wallet with gmail by using AuthKit.  but AAdemoUI seems not working.
I can only create wallet with MetaMask....
Anything should I modify or are there any newest version of demo UI?
https://safe-account-abstraction-demo.netlify.app/